# Convert string to integer in python

Tags: python, string

```
def handle_client_move(req):
    strmove = req.decode('utf-8')
    strmove = strmove[-1:]
    sendmove = strmove.strip()
    print(int(sendmove))
    strmove = '--' + strmove
    return(strmove)
```

I get this errror :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

cant convert strmove to integer.

Comment: Are you passing an empty string? Try adding exception handling via `try..except`

Comment: We need a main program to reproduce this error.

Comment: You should strip before `strmove[-1:]` and not the other way around

Comment: There's nowhere in your code where you try convert `strmove` into an integer. Please post the actual code you are running and the complete error message including the traceback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle this specific problem, where you're trying to convert an empty string to an integer, you could do this:

```
int(strmove or 0)
```

When `strmove` is the empty string, which is falsey, `strmove or 0` evaluates to `0` and that works fine as an argument to `int()`. You could also use some other number if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time with this :). it worked. my problem was an empty string in the first call. now it returns 0 for that, and returns proper integer values for all other calls.

Comment: You don't need to make `0` a `str()`, just doing `int(strmove or 0)` is more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

`strmove[-1:]` will give you only last symbol in your string. If it is whitespace then `strmove.strip()` will return empty string. Your error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

says that `''` (empty string) is invalid literal for integer (which is true).

So depending on what you want, you probably need to `strip()` before `strmove[-1:]`, or something else.